# Moving an imageButton up in the code crashes the app

Tags: android, xml

I have a main relativeLayout which contains :

1. a relative layout with a bunch of buttons inside
2. A sliding drawer
3. setting imageButton

The app works fine, but when i open the drawer i have the settings button on top of it, which i don't want, i want the drawer to hide it, so i moved the imageButton above the sliding drawer in the code, but this crashes my app. Why? it doesn't make any sense, is there another way to make the imageButton be behind the drawer?

EDIT: here's the code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/img_blue_background" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_call"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/left_divider"
        android:background="@drawable/img_transparent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_call_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_directions"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_divider"
        android:background="@drawable/img_transparent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_directions_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_voice"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center_divider"
        android:background="@drawable/img_transparent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_microphone_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_music"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/right_divider"
        android:background="@drawable/img_transparent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_music_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/center_divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_icon_divider" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_directions"
        android:src="@drawable/img_icon_divider" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_voice"
        android:src="@drawable/img_icon_divider" />

</RelativeLayout>



<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/time" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/time"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_widget_holder"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/widgetHolder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|right|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</SlidingDrawer>

        <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_transparent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img_settings_icon" />
```

Comment: Maybe in the layout of your ImageButton you make a reference to an ID which is not created yet (with @+id)... You should post your layout file

Comment: Are you getting an exception thrown?

Comment: If fiddler's advice doesn't help, please post the XML and LogCat errors. Otherwise we probably won't be able to help you without seeing what is happening.

Comment: The app compiles well, but it crashes after start it on the cell phone

Comment: Ok i found a solution, i deleted the buggy ImageButton and i've put another one with the same parameters, now it works :|